# Apache: Is there a way to use REMOTE_USER in a FilesMatch?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication

Username: `foo@foobar.com`

So what's the best way to allow the user to access any files that begin with his name? (eg foo_bar.pdf, foo.txt, footree.log)

```
# ... other authentication stuff here ...

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} ^(.*?)@
<FilesMatch "%1.*?\..*">
   require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```